# Layout per module zf2

Tags: php, templates, module, zend-framework2, zend-layout

I have 2 modules, and I need to use different layout for each one, but all modules always use layout of second loaded module.

*application.config.php* :

```
return array(
// This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
'modules' => array(
    'news',//in this module use Application layout
    'Application',
),
```

Comment: Well, when returning ViewModel from controller's action, you always can override default layout

Answer (score 2):

You could use [EdpModuleLayouts](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts). It is a ZF2 module that allows you to configure different layout for each module. Its usage is very simple :

- Just install it in your *vendor* folder of you project
- Enable `EdpModuleLayouts` module in the `application.config.php` file :

  ```
  'modules' => array(
  'EdpModuleLayouts', //<---add this line
  'News',
  'Application',
  ),
  ```
- Define the layout for each module in your `module.config.php` file of one of two modules, for example in the Application module. Here we are setting two layouts: `news/layout` for *News* Module and `layout/layout` for *Application* module :

  ```
  'view_manager' => array(
  'display_not_found_reason' => true,
  'display_exceptions'       => true,
  'doctype'                  => 'XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL',
  'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
  'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
  'template_map' => array(
      'news/layout'    => __DIR__ . '/../../News/view/layout/admin-layout.phtml',
      'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
      'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
      'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
      'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
  ),
  'template_path_stack' => array(
      'application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
      'news' => __DIR__ . '/../../News/view',
  ),
  ),

  'module_layouts' => array(
          'Application' => 'layout/layout',
          'News' => 'news/layout',
  ),
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set in your `{MyNewModule}/Module.php`.

   ```
   namespace {MyNewModule};

   use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
   use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
   use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;
   use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
   ```
2. Create a new Method Init.

   ```
   public function init(ModuleManager $manager){

   $events = $manager->getEventManager();
   $sharedEvents = $events->getSharedManager();
   $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
       $controller = $e->getTarget();
       $controller->layout('layout/***customFile.phtm***');
   }, 100);

   }
   ```
3. F5, recharge you browser.
4. Smile :D

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same case and solve it like this:

Had the module `login` and `application`, what I did was to determine the layouts in `global.php` like this:

```
return array(
     'module_layouts' => array(
        'Application' => 'layout/layout.phtml',
        'Login' => 'layout/login.phtml' 
),
);
```

Now you should create a folder in the view layout login, where would the `login.phtml`

now in the configuration of login module. `Module.config.php`

```
      'view_manager' => array(
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                'Login' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            ), 
          )
;
```

This should run you.

Comment: Please speak English or if you can't google translator might help